# Devise test helper fails to sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, minitest, devise-token-auth

I have a rails API app using devise_token_auth and in my tests (minitest) I need to send POST requests and signed in users so I used the `sign_in` method but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

This is my test file

```
require 'test_helper'

class ActivityControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
    test "post activity" do
        sign_in users('one')
        post '/activity/', params: {
            original_activity_log_file: fixture_file_upload('files/test_gpx.gpx', 'application/gpx'),
            title: 'test activity',
            description: 'test description'
        }
        assert_response 200
    end
end
```

And this is the result when run

```
Expected response to be a <200: OK>, but was a <401: Unauthorized>
Response body: {"errors":["You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."]}.
Expected: 200
  Actual: 401
```

What could be going on here to cause the test to fail?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `devise_token_auth` in that case plain devise helpers doesn't work, you need perform plain authorization with post request. Here is an **example**:

```
# make a request in order to get tokens
post(
  api_user_session_path,
  params: {
    email: "foo@bar.com",
    password: "password"
  }.to_json,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
  }
)
# fetch data from response
client = response.headers['client']
token = response.headers['access-token']
expiry = response.headers['expiry']
token_type = response.headers['token-type']  
uid = response.headers['uid']  
auth_params = {
  'access-token' => token,
  'client' => client,
  'uid' => uid,
  'expiry' => expiry,
  'token_type' => token_type
}
new_client = users('one')
get(
  api_find_client_by_name_path(new_client.name),
  headers: auth_params
)               
assert_response :ok
```

Comment: I don't have a `api_find_client_by_name_path` path in my app or anything with a similar name

Comment: it's an __example__, your actual path might be different.